# Returns all files in the folder, not just the last file

Tags: python

I have this function and through this function I want to pass through all the files within the folder and then return them, but the problem is that only the last file is returned.

How can I solve this problem?

```
def read_corpus_file_and_delete_stop_words():
    stop_words_list = stopwords.words('english')
    additional_stopwords = []

    with open("C:/Users/Super/Desktop/IR/homework/Lab4/IR Homework/stop words.txt", 'r') as file:
        for word in file:
            word = word.split('\n')
            additional_stopwords.append(word[0])

    stop_words_list += additional_stopwords

    dir_path = 'C:/Users/Super/Desktop/IR/homework/Lab4/corpus/corpus/'
    save_dir = "C:/Users/Super/Desktop/IR/homework/Files_Without_SW/"

    for document in os.listdir(dir_path):
        with open(dir_path + document, "r") as reader:
            save_file = open(save_dir + document, 'w')
            text = reader.read()
            text_tokens = word_tokenize(text)
            tokens_without_sw = [word.replace(',', ' ').replace('.', ' ') for word in text_tokens if
                                 (word not in stop_words_list)]
            save_file.writelines(["%s " % item.replace(',', ' ').replace('.', ' ') for item in tokens_without_sw])
            # print(document, ':', tokens_without_sw)
        return tokens_without_sw
```

Comment: Are you sure there are more files in the folder? Your code looks OK to me. Try call just 

import os
print(os.listdir('C:/Users/Super/Desktop/IR/homework/Lab4/corpus/corpus/'))

Comment: Can you give an example of what you *expect* your function to return? It looks to me as though it will return just the *first* file.

Comment: @RomanPavelka: How can: `Your code looks OK to me`? There is an early return!

Comment: @quamrana is right move the return back

Comment: @fthomson: Moving the `return` forward or back will make very little difference, ie the code will still only return one file.

Comment: based on the function name I assumed he was just trying to remove delete the stop words in each file which he does when he writes to save_file. I don't think the return statement is even needed tbh. Just my interpretation.

Comment: @fthomson: Well, we may never know....

Comment: @qumrana lol, you are right.... spot on, that is it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean to return `tokens_without_sw` for *every* file, in a `list`?

```py
def read_corpus_file_and_delete_stop_words():
    stop_words_list = stopwords.words('english')
    additional_stopwords = []

    with open("C:/Users/Super/Desktop/IR/homework/Lab4/IR Homework/stop words.txt", 'r') as file:
        for word in file:
            word = word.split('\n')
            additional_stopwords.append(word[0])

    stop_words_list += additional_stopwords

    dir_path = 'C:/Users/Super/Desktop/IR/homework/Lab4/corpus/corpus/'
    save_dir = "C:/Users/Super/Desktop/IR/homework/Files_Without_SW/"

    files_without_sw = []
    for document in os.listdir(dir_path):
        with open(dir_path + document, "r") as reader:
            save_file = open(save_dir + document, 'w')
            text = reader.read()
            text_tokens = word_tokenize(text)
            tokens_without_sw = [word.replace(',', ' ').replace('.', ' ') for word in text_tokens if
                                 (word not in stop_words_list)]
            save_file.writelines(["%s " % item.replace(',', ' ').replace('.', ' ') for item in tokens_without_sw])
            # print(document, ':', tokens_without_sw)
            files_without_sw.append(tokens_without_sw)
    return files_without_sw
```

Comment: I had a folder called "Corpus" and this folder contained files inside,
I removed the stop words from each file within the folder and I saved these files that do not contain the stop words in a new folder called "save_file", and now how can I get these files back in the new folder

Comment: I don't understand the question. Perhaps you should create a new question on this site.